# Change the permissions of the files

Tags: permissions

I have a script to copy binary files to the remote machine and once the files are copied in the tmp file of the remote servers. It automatically sudo login to the host and does `cd /tmp` and `chmod 775` to copied files but it prompts me an error operation not permitted. Then again i will have to `sudo logout` and go to `/tmp` folder then change the permission manually and again sudo login to the host and then i have to install the binaries (/tmp/copied file).

**Note**: The binary file is owning full permissions

Is there a way where i can change permission of the copied file in the `/tmp` without sudo logout.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rsync` with `-a` option, considering you have a user at remote server same as the owner of files in your case binary files.

`-a` option in `rsync` transfer files form on machine to another with all attributes .